# DocuSign - JWT user token error consent_required (php sdk)

Tags: docusignapi

```
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"error";s:16:"consent_required";}
```

I don't want redirect user to make do login and than get code, i wanna use admin account for access token.

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`consent_required` means that the person being impersonated by your app has not yet granted consent.

Consent can be granted by the individual or by the org administrator (if your account has that feature).

I explain it all in my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent).